# Substrings and finding words in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

how can i track how many times a specific word appears in a text box then display the number of times found in a message box?

for example if i type this in a textbox: today is really hot, it is not very convinient to be outside, it is better if we go swimming

and i am looking for the word "is" troughout the sentence, it appears 3 times yet I am not sure how to make a code so it does count the times "is" is being found and then display it with a message:

"your word is found 3 times in this sentence"

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

in a single line of code, but you have to add some error checking as well.

string.Format("your word is found {0} times in this sentence",(textBox1.Text.Split(new char[]{' ','.'}).ToList().Find(s=>s.Equals("is")).Length +1).ToString());

Comment: oh..and in C#. Convert it to vb.